# What's the difference between Example and Sample?

Tags: word-choice, spanish

What's the difference between Example and Sample?

In Spanish it's the same word, but in English it is 2 different words. What is the difference?

Comment: An example is provided for purposes of illustration.  A sample is provided as proof of suitability.  Examples help in the learning process.  Samples help in decision making particularly in decisions to acquire.

Comment: Sample: *muestra* or *muestreo*.  Example: *ejemplo*.

Comment: Just a note, there is also an "English language learners" exchange for questions like this one, wherein someone is trying to learn English based on their understanding of another language (which might be why this was closed)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is one of those cases where the dictionary definitions aren't very helpful to differentiate the meanings.  The difference is a little subtle.

Think of a **sample** as a random selection from a group.  The selection doesn't need to be random, but that concept provides the flavor of the manner in which the selection is representative.  It is representative of the group in the sense that it came from the group, but it may or may not be the choice that best epitomizes the group.

An **example** is a selection from a group that epitomizes the group, something that can serve as a model.

Luis Valencia - MVP's comment raises computer-related use of the terms.  "Sample" is often used for a chunk of code, a formula, or other similar snippet that illustrates in a generic or abstract way how something is structured or used, often with just enough content to illustrate a specific aspect.  This might indicate whether something could be suitable to a purpose, or provide generic guidance on how it might be used.  "Example" is often applied to something more complete, that illustrates the usage in context to solve some problem.

Comment: look at this site here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/code-samples-and-sdks, see the top menu?, they have both Examples and samples,